# It is good to use proxy in the mac environment, but the error page load error net::ERR_TIMED_OUT is reported in the linux environment

Tags: chromedp

```
opts := append(chromedp.DefaultExecAllocatorOptions[:], chromedp.Flag("headless", true))
if ip != "" {
   opts = append(opts, chromedp.ProxyServer(ip))
}
alloctx, cancel := chromedp.NewExecAllocator(context.Background(), opts...)
defer cancel()
ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(alloctx,
   chromedp.WithLogf(log.Printf),
)
```

It can proxy normally in mac, but it reports an error in linux
Tip: page load error net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
With proxy ip

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that the server, on which your app is running (since you use call `chromedp.NewExecAllocator`, it's the same server where the browser is running), can not connect to the proxy. Please check the network connectivity between the server and the proxy.

If you believe that there is nothing wrong with the network, please provide a full demo to show the issue. It would be helpful to describe how the proxy is setup, so that others can reproduce the issue.